# port gtk programs to mac

Tags: macos, user-interface, gtk, x11, porting

Running X11/GTK programs on mac is quite a pain for me. It looks ugly, and it from time to time acts in weird ways. So I'm wondering what would be the natural choice to port a GTK program to Mac using native GUI frameworks like Cocoa. And by the way, is there any existing effort to manage such portings in a unified repository?

Comment: This would be a significant effort as Cocoa uses Objective-C, an object oriented language.  Gtk apps are typically in C, but can be in C++ (gtkmm).  Another issue is that you'd have to completely redo the user interface in the applications which would be time consuming in Interface Builder or newer Xcode.  Maybe renesiance (sp) would be helpful.  It's a project designed for use with GNUstep or Cocoa to build user interfaces without interface builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many parts of the GTK+ are already ported to OS X, see [the home page of the GTK+ - OS X](http://www.gtk.org/download/macos.php). So, in theory, you only have to re-compile your favorite GTK+ app on OS X with the Quartz back end to have it run natively. You mileage of course will vary.